# My coefficients / standard errors are too high in a Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, multinomial-distribution

I have a data set with 1 Dv and 24 IVs, with which I am running a Multinomial Logistic Regression. The DV has 14 unordered levels (a list of future plans for students). The IVs are come in various scales (e.g. parts per million, percentages, etc). When I run a MLR I get coefficients in the 5.0e-05 range. Standard errors around the same. My model is as follows:

```
mlr <- multinom(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + ... IVi,
                data = data.set)
```

when I calculate the Z values with....

```
mlr.zvalues <- summary(mlr)$coefficients / summary(mlr)$standard.errors
```

I get Z values in the thousands. I'm looking for suggestions regarding my assumptions and my calculations. Anything helps. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think these numbers are wrong or unexpected?

Comment: I am not sure what, 'my standard errors are too high' means. The standard errors are what they are. Why are you using z values with logistic regression?

Comment: check for multicollinearity among the predictors.

Comment: 14 classes is a challenge in general. How many instances do you have in the training data?

Comment: @Dave I thought that a Z value in the thousands sounded like a red flag. If they were in the + or - 10 range I wouldn't have much hesitation.

Comment: @rapaio I have about 38,000 respondents